# El uso de ctype en c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double cuota,dscto, importe=0;
char colegio, categoria;
int sw=0;
cout<<"Ingresar colegio de procedencia (N)acional,(P)articular:";
cin>>colegio;
cout<<" Ingresar categoria (A,B,C):";
cin >>categoria;
cout<<"Ingresar cuota:";
cin>>cuota;
colegio=tolower(colegio);
categoria=tolower(categoria);
siwtch (colegio)
{
    case ´n´
        break;
    }
        switch (categoria)
        {
            case ´a´: dscto=.50*cuota;break;
            case ´b´: dscto=.40*cuota;break;
            case ´c´: dscto=.30*cuota;break;
            default: cout<<"Opcion no contemplada";
            sw=1;

        }
        break;
        case ´p´:
            switch(categoria)
            {case ´a´:dscto=.25*cuota;break;
         case ´b´:dscto=.20*cuota;break;
         case ´c´:dscto=.15*cuota;break;
         sw=1;
            }
        break;
        default: cout<<"Opcion no contemplada";
            sw=1;

    }
        if (sw==0)
        {
        importe=cuota-dscto;
        cout<<"El importe a pagar es:"<<importe;
    }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

Al compilar me sale:

> [Error] ctype: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Comment: veo caracateres extraños en el switch como: `´n´` , podrias corregirlo

Comment: tambien veo otros errores tipográficos como `siwtch`, deberia ser `switch`

Comment: cambia la importación a `#include<ctype.h>`

Comment: o mejor usa `#include<cctype>`

Answer (score 0):

Las librerías heredadas de C se encuentran en dos formatos:

- nombre antiguo, el mismo que en C: `stdio.h`
- nombre nuevo, desaparece la extensión y se añade una `c` al inicio: `cstdio`

Ahora bien, la librería `ctype`, en C se encuentra con este nombre: `ctype.h`, luego para utilizarla en C++ podremos usar:

```
#include <ctype.h> // Nombre C
#include <cctype>  // Nombre C++
```

Por otro lado tu programa posee varios errores en el código:

- `siwtch` debería ser `switch`

  ```
  siwtch (colegio) // <<--- MAL
  switch (colegio) // <<--- BIEN
  ```
- Los caracteres se indican con el caracter `'` en vez de `´`. Los case, además, van también con dos puntos:

  ```
  case ´n´  // <<--- MAL
  case 'n': // <<--- BIEN
  ```
- No es demasiado recomendable anidar instrucciones `switch`. Es preferible dividir el código en funciones
- Vigila las llaves. Hay `break` e instrucciones `case` fuera de los `switch`:

  ```
  switch (colegio)
  {
    case 'n':
      break;
  }

  switch (categoria)
  {
      case 'a': dscto=.50*cuota;break;
      case 'b': dscto=.40*cuota;break;
      case 'c': dscto=.30*cuota;break;
      default: cout<<"Opcion no contemplada";
      sw=1;

  }
  break; // <<--- Por ejemplo este
  ```